# How do the `export` and `declare` modifiers differ in an ambient context (a .d.ts file) in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In particular, what I would like to know is how the following modifiers differ in behavior when used inside an ambient context in a `.d.ts` file.

1. `type`
2. `export type`
3. `declare type`
4. `export declare type`

I've been looking for answers online, which is starting to get more confusing with each new piece of info I find around the different ways to use an ambient module.

From what I understand, I am able to `import` `type`s that are declared as option (1) in other modules, which confuses me as to what difference it has with declaring as option (2). Declaring as option (3) makes it available globally so that you do not have to `import` the type in other modules, as long as it is `declare`d in the global scope, which, again, begs the question, what's the use of option (4)? Does `export`ing only make sense if you're developing a library?

I suppose they all have their niche use-cases which I'm failing to understand. I'd appreciate any help that would lead me in the right direction in understanding their differences—thanks in advance!

Comment: Using any **static** import or export statements of any kind will result in the file becoming a *module* file and not an *ambient context* file.